# show more option is not working with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to add limit each time when button is **clicked** but is not **working**

my html code is

```
 <div class="media stream load-more">
    <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method ='post' name = 'showmore'>
        <i class="icon-refresh shaded"></i>
            show more...
    </a>
</div>
```

php code is

```
$showvalue = 2;
if(isset($_POST['showmore'])) {
     $showvalue += 1;
}

$feeds = $db->getfeeds($showvalue);
```

mysql function

```
public function getfeeds($showvalue){
      $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id,image,title,status,profilepic,created_at,url FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $showvalue");
      $stmt->bind_param("s",$showvalue);
      $stmt->execute();
      $result = $stmt->get_result();

      $nrow = array();

    while ($r = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

       $nrow[] = $r;
    }
       $frow['news'] = $nrow;
    $json = str_replace("\\/", "/",json_encode($frow));
    return $json;

   }
```

Comment: is it `<a href....` or `<form...` ??, where is form? u r using `$_POST['showmore']`

Comment: @devpro it is new type of elements, introduces week ago and called `aform` ;)

Comment: i know i can post value from form but with <a herf how i can do it

Comment: than u can use query string.

Comment: Just do `<a href="?showmore=1">...</a>` and search for $_GET['showmore']

Comment: dont know how to do it i am a beginner in coding can u pls tell me how can i do it

Comment: I've just showed you how to do it

Comment: To get a complete answer you will also need to show how you generate the HTML as you will also have to make sure it get regenerated with a new value for `showmore` every roundtrip